# Monogame - draw automatically generated content from curves

Tags: c#, pixel, collision, monogame

I am writing a little Monogame and I am wondering how I can draw a curve that will be generated by some formula, then I want to fill everything bellow that curve with some color and I want to generate things on the top and drop them down until they collide with the curve. Check the image for a better understanding of my issue.

[image]

What type of object I should use for this kind of objects?

Alternative: If the curve and filled area cant be generated automatically or it is too hard to implement, I can make an image where the "unfilled" area is simply invisible, but I still get to the same issue, how to set the bounds such that they match the visible parts of the image and ignore the invisible?

Or even simpler how to get the top Y bound value for a given X value?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution here [Per Pixel Collision - Could do with some general tips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14894796/per-pixel-collision-could-do-with-some-general-tips) basicly it does a color detection collision.